# Is there a way that fully managed device under android management api stays enrolled after factory reset?

Tags: android, django, api, android-management-api

I enroll the device using qrCode and have not disabled factory reset.
But once I factory reset the device, the device no longer stays enrolled and becomes a simple personal phone.

Is there a way, the device stays enrolled after factory reset or any soft reset functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider [Zero-Touch Enrollment](https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device#zero-touch_enrollment). With this method, the admins can create configurations containing the provisioning details and devices will automatically provision themselves on first boot or after a factory reset. ZeroTouch capability requires the devices be purchased from an [authorized zero-touch reseller](https://www.android.com/enterprise/management/zero-touch/). Please take note that even though the device stays enrolled, after factory reset, the user data will be deleted. You may refer to this [documentation](https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/7514005?hl=en) for more information.

Comment: Is there a way of implementing zero-touch enrollment on a Buy Your Own Device (BYOD)?

Answer (score 1):

No. Once device is reset the max security is frp admin id, that's it! AM API is gone after reset.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).